# Questions regarding Node.js syntax

Tags: node.js, node-modules

everyone!

I am reading some code in an attempt to learn node.js, it's available [here](https://github.com/mohsen1/fb-photo-fetch).

Anyways, I have a few questions regarding some of the syntax of JS. The first bits are in index.html

1.

```
var argv = require("minimist")(process.argv.slice(2), {
default: { albums: true }
});
```

What is going on after the comma? Are we setting default values? We never declared albums, so then how are we setting a default value?

2.

What do we call it when we have a module, then a statement in parenthesis? Is this part of overriding the constructor?

```
var sinceDate = require("moment")(argv.sinceDate, "YYYY/MM/DD");
var sinceDate = require("moment")(argv.sinceDate, "YYYY/MM/DD");
if (!sinceDate.isValid()) {
  require("debug")("download")(
    "invalid sinceDate '" +
      argv.sinceDate +
      "', date filter disabled (get all)."
  );
  sinceDate = 0;
}
```

In get_all.js , it is used in the third line.

```
var debug = require("debug")("json");
```

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I think when you `require('debug')` and others you get a function and that gets invoked here.

Comment: @vibhor1997a So, we are providing arguments in all three snippets?

Comment: Yes we are providing the arguments to the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand this you need to first understand in JavaScript function are `First-Class Functions`, mean functions can be treated as regular variables. Thus you can pass those as arguments to other functions aka `callbacks`, or you can return a function from a function aka `Closure`. Also you can store functions into another variables.

For more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/First-class_Function

Answers to your questions:

1.

```
var argv = require("minimist")(process.argv.slice(2), {
default: { albums: true }
});
```

What is going on after the comma? Are we setting default values? We never declared albums, so then how are we setting a default value?

> Answer:

Yes we are setting default values, but not for the variables you declared rather you are passing these default values to "minimist" module. This module is probably using `albums` and what you asked it that the default value for `albums` is true.

2.

What do we call it when we have a module, then a statement in parenthesis? Is this part of overriding the constructor?

```
var sinceDate = require("moment")(argv.sinceDate, "YYYY/MM/DD");
var sinceDate = require("moment")(argv.sinceDate, "YYYY/MM/DD");
if (!sinceDate.isValid()) {
  require("debug")("download")(
    "invalid sinceDate '" +
      argv.sinceDate +
      "', date filter disabled (get all)."
  );
  sinceDate = 0;
}
```

In get_all.js , it is used in the third line.

```
var debug = require("debug")("json");
```

> Answer:

As we discussed above functions being `First-Class Functions`. Here the "moment" module is returning a constructor function and you are calling that constructor function just after requiring it. Though it can be done as follow:

```
var moment = require("moment");
var sinceDate = moment(argv.sinceDate, "YYYY/MM/DD");
```

In above code, I required moment library once and  used it as constructor function for `sinceDate`.

The same concept is for module `debug`, its returning a function and you are calling that function just after require with argument `json`.